# Making the locale time format more compact

Tags: debian, date, locale, time, dmesg

`dmesg -T` gives human readable time format, and I want to make it more compact, from this

```
[Пт мар 12 09:18:54 2021] wlan0: associated
```

to this

```
[12.03.21 09:18:54] wlan0: associated
```

I'm using ru_RU.UTF-8 locale and the current date/time format looks like dmesg uses this locale settings too. So I have edited /usr/share/i18n/locales/ru_RU like this:

```
date_fmt "%d.%m.%y %T"
d_t_fmt "%d.%m.%y %T"
d_fmt     "%d.%m.%y"
t_fmt     "%T"
```

But after locale-gen I don't see any differences in dmesg -T date/time format, it's still the same. Rebooting does not help too.

The output of date command have changed how I wanted:

```
root@PC1:~# date
12.03.21 09:42:17
```

I'd like to understand where dmesg gets settings for date/time format and how to change them.

```
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
            Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-14-amd64
```

I know about --time-format and all corresponding printf possibilities to change output of dmesg, but I want to have more compact date systemwide. I thought Linux has single point of locale settings, and I wonder why editing of locales do not do the trick with dmesg.